# Can't locate File/Glob.pm in @INC (@INC contains: D:/tools/lib .) at directory.pl line 2

Tags: perl, locate

I get this error when running my perl code

`Can't locate File/Glob.pm in @INC (@INC contains: D:/tools/lib .) at directory.pl line 2.`

`line 2: @files=<*>;`

When i run the command,  I get,

`Y:\perl\perl>perldoc -l File::Glob`

`D:\tools\lib\perl\510\File\Glob.pm`

So I think the File::Glob module is installed?

Comment: It's installed, alright. Your `@INC` doesn't point to it, though.

Comment: Thanks, somehow I thought it would know how to search the subpath under D:/tools/lib

Comment: Why does perldoc find it if it's not in @INC

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`@INC` should be set correctly upon installation of Perl. When it doesn't match your configuration, you seem to have messed up something.

However, if the current value of `@INC` doesn't fit your needs, you have various options:

1. Add `D:\tools\lib\perl\510\` to the
   environment variable `PERL5LIB` (or `PERLLIB` if this doesn't work)
2. Specify `@INC` on startup: 
   `perl -I D:\tools\lib\perl\510\`
3. Instead of writing `use libname`, you can write `use path/to/libname`
4. Using a `BEGIN` block before the `use` statements:

   ```
   BEGIN {
     push @INC,"D:\tools\lib\perl\510\";
   }
   ```

See also http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html for a short introduction.

Comment: resolved using the first suggestion; and thanks for providing so many alternative!     "There's more than one way to do it"- I guess :)

Comment: I guess, you should refrain from using slashes in Perl code under Windows, since these `"\t"`, `"\510"` etc may be expanded to some weird characters.  Using backslashes would be more appropriate, I guess.